# How to convert Two dimensional array to call from PROGMEM

Tags: arduino

I have a very large array that I don't want to use up my precious SRAM. There's also a helper array that i'd like in PROGMEM as well.

The arrays are:

```
fontLookUp[265]
font[96][8]
```

Using these arrays I get the data for a character by calling a process eight times(one for each of the eight bytes per character) which references this address:

```
font[fontLookUp[character]][x]
```

I only know how to read single dimensional arrays from PROGMEM... How would I handle the second dimension [x]?

Answer (score 1):

an array is just a pointer to a memory address.

```
int font [3][5];
int font [15];
```

are equivalents so:

```
font[2][1];
font[2*5+1]; // multiply by the 5 in font[3][->5<-]
*(font+2*5+1);
```

you just treat the multidimensional array as a sigledimmensional.

Comment: so "font[fontLookUp[character]][x]" would look like "(pgm_read_byte(font + pgm_read_byte(fontLookUp + character) * 8 + x))" ?? I tried this and it isn't working correctly.

Comment: you forgot the ->*<- at the begin, that * returns the value pointed by font. Also you have to know that one char uses only 1 byte (8 bits), so I don't understant why you are using this 8 bytes.

Comment: font[fontLookUp[character]][x] should be something like: *(font+fontLookUp[character]*8+x)  This is untested code.